# Redis on Heroku saving multiple hash keys as one. But OK on local redis db

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

We are having an issue with heroku-redis where new hash keys are being saved in the same value

scan 0 gives us the following on heroku

`1) "0"
2) 1448734352609, 1448734366659, 1448734356829`

whereas on localhost we have the following:

`1) "0"
2) 1) "1448734352609"
   2) "1448734366659"
   3) "1448734356829"`

Our code to add the hashes is the same and has not been changed. We are using the redis NPM module. Just unable to figure out why it is not working on Heroku. Help would be appreciated.

[Link to my project](https://github.com/sohilpandya/google-places-analytics/blob/master/lib/emailform.js#L1)

Hope I have been thorough with the information, let me know if you need any more. :)

Comment: What versions of Redis are you using locally and on Heroku? What commands are you using to add new items to Redis?

Comment: Local version of Redis is 3.0.5 

Here is the bit of code that is being used. 

`client.hmset(request.params.email, "name", request.params.name, "email", request.params.email, "location", request.params.location );`


 I have tried to use timestamp as well as email for the hash and get the same result. ( replacing `request.params.email` with `timestamp` ) 

Heroku version is also 3.0.5. so no difference there.

Comment: curious if this might be because your other libraries are different. What happens if you try both on a clean git clone locally and a clean new heroku app?

Comment: @Zlatko that may work, although I think the redis client display from heroku maybe the real issue here, as the data from it is intact.

Will give it a go with the way you've said though!

Answer (score 1):

The input of the items was different. Perhaps the version of Node that added the values? Not sure.

The Heroku example is 3 numbers, the local example is 3 strings.